# Белая обводка у рамки

Tags: html, css

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти откуда появляется белая обводка у рамки фотографии.

```css
.thumbnail img {
  /*Параметры изображения-миниатюры*/
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  margin: 3px 3px 3px 2px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.thumbnail:hover {
  /*Параметры изображения-миниатюры*/
  background-color: transparent;
}

.thumbnail span img {
  /*Параметры увеличенного изображения*/
  border-width: 0;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 575px;
  height: 384px;
}

.thumbnail span {
  /*Параметры увеличенного изображения*/
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #E6E6FA;
  padding: 5px;
  visibility: hidden;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.thumbnail:hover span {
  /*Параметры увеличенного изображения*/
  visibility: visible;
  top: 0;
  left: 365px;
  /*Позиция увеличенного изображения*/
}
```

```html
<a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" /><span><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" /><br />Летний этюд</span></a>
```

[image: Белая рамка]

Comment: Добавьте `HTML`

Comment: вроде border нигде нет, откуда она взялась ума не приложу

Comment: Так Вы же сами написали  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;

Comment: здесь используется 2 картинки,у миниатюры должны быть, а у увеличенного не должна

Comment: .thumbnail img {
  /*Параметры изображения-миниатюры*/
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;

Comment: это все правильно, там должна быть

Answer (score 3, accepted):

у вас в стилях написано .thumbnail  img. А это значит что вы задаете стили ВСЕМ img внутри thumbnail. Большая картинка тоже попадает под эти стили.

Сделайте стили именно по миниатюру - .thumbnail > img или для миниатюры отдельный класс

Answer (score 1):

```
.thumbnail span {
  /*Параметры увеличенного изображения*/
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #E6E6FA; // это дает цвет рамки
  padding: 5px; //размер рамки
```

Обводки белой нет на этом [примере](https://codepen.io/Dimas_X/pen/jKpOGv)

Comment: это цвет дает у всей рамки, это понятно, но там есть белая полоска, которую нигде не прописывал, вроде, как ее убрать?

Comment: Я на codepen залил пример. Нет там обводки белой.

Comment: Возможно браузер подставляет ее от миниатюры. Пропишите напрямую для увеличенного изображения border: none

Answer (score 1):

Как я уже писал в комментах Вы сами указали `border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;` .Hover ничего не меняет

Comment: там как вы могли заметить по html коду, там 2 картинки используются, одна для миниатюры, другая для увеличенного изображения. У миниатюры есть рамка, я ее прописал, а вот у увеличенного изображения тоже появилась рамка, хотя там этого нет

Answer (score 1):

Заккоментируйте background-color.

```
.thumbnail span{ /*Параметры увеличенного изображения*/ 
position: absolute; 
/*background-color: #E6E6FA;*/ 
padding: 5px; 
visibility: hidden; 
color: black; 
text-decoration: none; 
}
```